# 302 Redirection https to http is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect

I want to redirect website from https to http 302. I am using below code:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{www.example.com}/ [L,R=302]
```

But it is not working. How can I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can add below code in your project root .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

Comment: I have tried multiple times.

Comment: May be in your htaccess file write other rules that will redirect your url to "http to https" after adding above code.

Comment: He wants to 302 redirect not 301

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check it.